# https_proxy variable unset in batch file

Tags: windows, proxy

Does Windows treat `https_proxy` differently in batch files?

I have a Windows batch file that sets up some things in my environment. It has some lines like the following (forgive the debugging - it's relevant)

```
set http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.server:8888
set https_proxy=%http_proxy%
set httpz_proxy=%http_proxy%
```

If I run that batch file then check what got set:

```
> echo %https_proxy%
%https_proxy%

> echo %httpz_proxy%
http://user:pass@proxy.server:8888
```

So it's actually treating `https_proxy` differently than other variables. I even tried nonsense like:

```
set var=https_proxy
set %var%=%http_proxy%
```

This works as expected when I type it in the command prompt, but it still won't run from the batch file. I even tried even more insane nonsense in case `https_proxy` literal was being skipped:

```
set var1=http
set var2=s_proxy
set %var1%%var2%=%http_proxy%
```

and this works when I run it in the prompt, but not from the batch file. Of course, using any other variable name works fine in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

With all the things I tried, I didn't try the same commands in a different batch file. There must have been some non-printable character messing things up - it's just very odd that changing the variable name in that one line would change the behavior. Retyping the whole file sorted things out.